# Connect to active directory through LDAP-Ruby

Tags: ruby, active-directory, ldap, windows-server

I'm trying to connect to an AD instance from my Ruby application. I've chosen LDAP for the job.

Below is my connection settings and script I've written.

```
 def name_for_login( email, password )
  email = email[/\A\w+/].downcase  # Throw out the domain, if it was there
  email << "@example.com"        # I only check people in my company
  ldap = Net::LDAP.new(
    host: '10.0.0.2',
    port: 1027,
    auth: { method: :simple, email: email, password:password }
  )
  if ldap.bind
  p 'lol'
    # Yay, the login credentials were valid!
    # Get the user's full name and return it
    ldap.search(
      base:         "OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=example,DC=com",
      filter:       Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "mail", email ),
      attributes:   %w[ displayName ],
      return_result:true
    ).first.displayName.first
  end
end
```

and test credentials:

1. windows : Windows@test
2. tester : Pass@123

If I run the script, it throws me the following error :

```
irb(main):025:0> name_for_login('tester','Pass@123')
Net::LDAP::BindingInformationInvalidError: Invalid binding information
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ldap-0.16.1/lib/net/ldap/auth_adapter/simple.rb:14:in `bind'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ldap-0.16.1/lib/net/ldap/connection.rb:278:in `block in bind'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ldap-0.16.1/lib/net/ldap/instrumentation.rb:19:in `instrument'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ldap-0.16.1/lib/net/ldap/connection.rb:275:in `bind'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ldap-0.16.1/lib/net/ldap.rb:868:in `block in bind'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ldap-0.16.1/lib/net/ldap/instrumentation.rb:19:in `instrument'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ldap-0.16.1/lib/net/ldap.rb:860:in `bind'
    from (irb):9:in `name_for_login'
    from (irb):25
    from /usr/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I'm unsure from where to troubleshoot to understand the problem.

The AD is on a Windows server hosted on Azure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Ruby, but my guess is that the problem is here:

```
auth: { method: :simple, email: email, password:password }
```

According to [the documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-net-ldap/Net/LDAP), you should be using the `username` property, not `email`. And you need to set it to either the username (`sAMAccountName`) of the account, or the `userPrincipalName` (which may be the same as the email address, or the `distinguishedName`.

Assuming the `userPrincipalName` is the same as the email address, then this might work:

```
auth: { method: :simple, username: email, password:password }
```

Comment: What's the general format for the following for an AD? 
Username, Password and HOST. I've seen multiple posts and there's no structured format. Is there a particular working schema that works for LDAP-AD?

Comment: Host is just the server name or IP. Password is your password; nothing special there. And username is what I described in my answer.

Comment: Username for AD LDAP connections should be in the following format: sAMAccountName@domain.  For your example it would be windows@example.com and tester@example.com